# making faces of a sword smooth with

Tags: rendering, shaders, edges

Hi im making a sword at the moment in blender and was wondering if anyone knows how to make certain faces smooth in render while maintaining the sharp edge of the sword, in the attached image I've selected the faces i'm trying to smooth out. I did select the edges running the width of the sword and use 'w' to smooth edges which helped a bit but didn't make it much better.
if anyone has any tricks i'd appreciate it.
Cheers
[image: edit mode]

[image: rendered]

Comment: In general you want to model with faces that have four vertices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn on smooth shading and then use autosmooth so the smooth shading doesn't effect the sharp edges.

To enable smooth shading: in the pannel of the left, which you bring up by pressing T, click on the smooth option under shading. [image: smooth shading]

To enable autosmooth: In the section on the right with render settings and material click on the tab with a icon of 3 vertices connected. [image: vertex panel]

Tick the autosmooth option.

[image: Tick autosmooth]

Comment: Please include steps as to *how* the user can turn on smooth shading and autosmooth.

Comment: @RayMairlot added them

Answer (score 0):

Subdivision Surface modifier will make everything smoother. Then, you can add loop cuts for your sharp ends. Also enable "Smooth Shading" from your panel on the left (Shortcut "T") and you will have a smooth mesh. If you'd like to add groves, or a slant to it, you can always add another loop cut on the blade (Shortcut "CTRL+R" in edit mode) and move certain vertices higher.